# Vue Event Bus - $on works with fat arrow function but not 'traditional' function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I was having a lot of trouble figuring out why I wasn't able to have an event bus listener update one of my components.

Below, in one of my component files, my `server` data property wouldn't get properly updated when using a traditional function accepting the outside `server` argument:

```
<template>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <p v-if="!server">Please select a server</p>
        <p v-else>Server #{{ server.id }} selected, Status: {{ server.status }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { serverBus } from '../../main.js';

    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                server: null
            }
        },
        created() {
            /* DOESNT WORK */
            serverBus.$on('serverSelected', function(server) {
                this.server = server;
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

However, once I change `serverBus.$on` to accept a fat arrow as its parameter receiving the server, it works and the `<p v-else>` gets properly triggered after the server is no longer null.

```
<template>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <p v-if="!server">Please select a server</p>
        <p v-else>Server #{{ server.id }} selected, Status: {{ server.status }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { serverBus } from '../../main.js';

    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                server: null
            }
        },
        created() {
            /* WORKS */
            serverBus.$on('serverSelected', (server) => {
                this.server = server;
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Do you know why this is? I even did a console.log inside of the created() in the one that wasn't working, and the server information was getting properly logged... the `<p v-else>` just wasn't responding to the data `server` property no longer being null.

Here's my `$emit` portion, if it helps:

```
<script>
    import { serverBus } from '../../main.js';

    export default {
        props: ['server'],
        methods: {
            serverSelected() {
                serverBus.$emit('serverSelected', this.server);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Arrow functions bind `this`. Regular functions do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @RoyJ says, arrow functions are anonymous and change the way `this` binds in functions. Using the es5 syntax `function` creates a new context for `this`.

Consider the following:

```
var obj = {
  user: 'John',
  roles: ['Admin', 'Manager'],
  displayUserRoles: function () {
    return this.roles.map(function (role) { // es5 function
      return this.user + ' is a ' + role + '.'
    })
  }
}

obj.displayUserRoles()
// output would be
['undefined is a Admin.', 'undefined is a Manager.']
```

vs:

```
var obj = {
  user: 'John',
  roles: ['Admin', 'Manager'],
  displayUserRoles: function () {
    return this.roles.map(role => {  // es6 arrow function
      return this.user + ' is a ' + role + '.'
    })
  }
}

obj.displayUserRoles()
// output would be
['John is a Admin.', 'John is a Manager.']
```

Comment: @user320487 So does it mean that there is no way to make it work via es5 function ?